# Android Java - Passing data between intents but need to save it on main activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that for right now, consists of 2 buttons (will later consists of 20+). When I click on a button, it takes me to a new activity that has a list of items I can select. After selecting something and clicking the Back button, it starts a new activity that passes on the item's information (in this case, "orange") and then it assigns the word "orange" to the button that was clicked.

Now when I click on the other button to assign it's information, I lose all of my first button information. What are my options for saving the previous information? Would I have to create an intent for it and keep passing it back and forth between actvities?

At the end, I need to collect all the information that was assigned to both buttons and pass that onto another activity, as this is just the customizing page. Is there a way I can just have the Strings set such that leaving the activity won't delete the String information?

Here's my MainActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        btnValue = extras.getString("btnValue");
        itemValue = extras.getString("itemValue");
    }

    if (btnValue.equals("btn1")){
        btn1.setText(itemValue);
    } else if (btnValue.equals("btn2")) {
        btn2.setText(itemValue);
    }
}

public void onClickBtn1(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("btn", "btn1");
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

public void onClickBtn2(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("btn", "btn2");
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

and my 2nd activity

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        btnValue = extras.getString("btn");
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] values = new String[] { "apple", "banana", "orange", "cherry"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            itemPosition = position; 
            itemPositionString = String.valueOf(itemPosition);
        }
    });
}

public void onClickBack (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("btnValue", btnValue);
    intent.putExtra("itemValue", itemValue);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo sorry, what part was unclear? I just lose all my information when I am back on my main page and click on another button to assign it it's text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Android lifecycle to manage the activity's state.
To save the activity state you need to do your work on the method onSaveInstanceState.

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
```

On restoration you either check the bundle the following methods

```
onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
onCreate(Bundle bundle)
```

You can find more details here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

When you use `startActivity` it creates new activity. So you lose old information. You need to use `startActivityForResult` from MainActivity while starting second activity and from the second activity you should use `setResult`

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

And you handle the result in MainActivity with

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
..
..
}
```

Here, there is an example [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 3 choices:

1. Pass all data in the `Intent` and return any new/changed data in another `Intent` using `startActivityForResult()`.
2. Save the data in a `static` variable somewhere (globals). All activities can then reference the current data and make changes to it that are then seen by all other activities. This is the quick-and-dirty solution which is suitable for small, trivial or "homework" solutions.
3. Save the data in a persistent storage (a file or an SQLite database). All activities can read all the current data, display it and make changes. After the BACK button is pressed, the underlying `Activity` should read the current data from the persistent storage to refresh the views.